# Improvement in linklist intersection point program

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written below code for finding intersection point of linklist.
Can somebody please review the same and tell me is there any improvement I can do to make it better.

Algo-:

1. Taken two pointers p1 and p1 initialized at the head of LL-1 and LL-2, respectively. Then let them both traverse through the lists, one node at a time.
2. When p1 reaches the end of a list, then redirect it to the head of LL-2 and when p2 reaches the end of a list, redirect it the head of LL-1.
3. If at any point p1 meets p2, then p1/p2 is the intersection node.

   ```
   int getIntesectionNode(struct Node* head1, struct Node* head2)
   {
     struct Node *start1 = head1;
     struct Node *start2 = head2;

     bool endFound1 = false;
     bool endFound2 = false;

     if( start1 == NULL || start2 == NULL)
     {
      return -1;
     }

     while(1)
     {
      start1 = start1->next;
      start2 = start2->next;

      if( start1 != start2)
      {
        if( start1 == NULL)
        {
          if (endFound1)
          {
            printf("Intersection not found !");
            break;
          }
           start1 = head2;
           endFound1 = true;
        }

        if( start2 == NULL)
        {

          if (endFound2 )
          {
             printf("Intersection not found !");
             break;
          }
          start2 = head1;
          endFound2 = true;
        }
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Intersection point found\n");
         printf("%d",start1->data);
         return start1->data;
      }
    }
    return -1;
   }
   ```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work? If not, what errors do you get? Or how does the output differ from what you want?

Comment: It is working fine but I want to check is there any improvements which can be done to make it better.

Comment: What are the terminating conditions if you have two lists of length N?  The pointers in those lists will never meet, assuming that all the elements of the lists are distinct.  If either list has a loop in its tail, you're not guaranteed that there'll be an intersection point; it depends on where the two pointers are when the second pointer reaches the loop.  If both lists have a loop in the tail, then you're guaranteed the pointers won't intersect.  (Aside: it is a good idea to end print formats with a newline – a number of yours do not have a newline at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't understand, but if you are doing what I think,  I would use a second loop,
and check all of LL-1 foreach LL-2.   I would also check the starting point for equality
before starting the loop and going to the next point, without checking it until you loop around.